# Astro ssr can not find css files

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side-rendering, astrojs

Followed Astro instructions to build Astro app
But the app can not find the assets

Steps to produce:

1. Create empty astro project from template
2. Add @astro/node to project `npx astro add node`
3. Run `npm run build`
4. Serve the server `node ./dist/server/entry.mjs` as documentation said

It gives this error like below and doesn't apply css.

[image: asset not found error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you try with the latest version or provide the version you tested with.
I tried the same steps as you did, using

```
npx astro create
npx astro add node
```

which used version  `v1.6.15`
I did got a build error `Setting the 'mode' option is required` so I updated the `astro.config.js` to look as follows :

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';

// https://astro.build/config
import node from "@astrojs/node";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  output: "server",
  adapter: node({
    mode: 'standalone'
  })
});
```

after that build and run went smooth

```
npm run build
node ./dist/server/entry.mjs
```

as you can see css correctly loaded
[image]